# Deploying (non-Google Analytics) eCommerce tracking code - Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, transactions, woocommerce, analytics

Hoping you can help...

We've got a Wordpress/Woocommerce store - all set up and configured with Google Analytics eCommerce via a plugin. We have a third party CRM/Marketing tool, which also demands eCommerce track script to record transactions as Closed Won Opportunities.

Much like Google Analytics there are three methods
 1. Create a transaction object
 2. Add items to the transaction
 3. Tell CRM the transaction is complete

I've tested this all out by deploying the example as plugin. And am getting some data through to the CRM like total price and customer name.

What I cannot work out how to do is;
a) get the product name info
b) get the product category info
c) pass this through with more than one product i.e. splitting out the order so each product in the basket is shown

```
  <?php
    /**
    * Plugin Name: eCommerce Tracking
    * Plugin URI: 
    * Description: Send shopping data to CRM
     * Version: 1.0
    * Author: fly
* Author URI: 
* License: GPL2
*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_tracking' );
function my_custom_tracking( $order_id ) {



// Lets grab the order
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

// Order ID
$order_id = $order->get_order_number();

// Order total
$order_total = $order->get_total();

// Order e-mail
$order_email = $order->billing_email;

// Order Billing First Name
$order_fname = $order->billing_first_name;

// Order Billing Last Name
$order_lname = $order->billing_last_name;

// Order Billing Address 1
$order_bill1 = $order->billing_address_1;

// Order Billing Address 2
$order_bill2 = $order->billing_address_2;

// Billing City
$order_billcity = $order->billing_city;

// Billing State
$order_billstate = $order->billing_state;

// Billing Postcode
$order_billpostcode = $order->billing_postcode;

// Billing Country
$order_billcountry = $order->billing_country;

// Billing Phone
$order_billphone = $order->billing_phone;

// Order Tax Cost
$order_tax = $order->order_tax;

// Order Shipping Cost
$order_shippingcost = $order->order_shipping;

// Order Currency
$order_currency = $order->order_currency;

// Product Category
$order_category = $order->term_id;

// Product Name
$order_product = $order->item_id;

// Product Quantity
$order_quantity = $order->quantity;

// Product SKU
$order_sku = $order->sku;

// Product Price
$order_price = $order->price;


?>



<!-- Start Tracking code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _ss = _ss || [];
_ss.push(['_setDomain', 'xxxxxxxx']);
_ss.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxxxxx']);
_ss.push(['_trackPageView']);
(function() {
var ss = document.createElement('script');
ss.type = 'text/javascript'; ss.async = true;

ss.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' :     
'http://') + 'koi-3Q40EJNC5K.marketingautomation.services/client/ss.js?  
ver=1.1.1';
var scr = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
scr.parentNode.insertBefore(ss, scr);
})();
</script>



<script type='text/javascript'>

_ss.push(['_setTransaction', {
    'transactionID': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
    'storeName': 'Reco Surfaces',
    'total': '<?php echo $order_total; ?>',
    'tax': '<?php echo $order_tax; ?>',
    'shipping': '<?php echo $order_shippingcost; ?>',
    'city': '<?php echo $order_billcity; ?>',
    'state': '<?php echo $order_billstate; ?>',
    'zipcode': '<?php echo $order_billpostcode; ?>',
    'country': 'UK',
    'firstName' : '<?php echo $order_fname; ?>', 
    'lastName' : '<?php echo $order_lname; ?>', 
    'emailAddress' : '<?php echo $order_email ?>' 
}, function() {

    _ss.push(['_addTransactionItem', {
        'transactionID': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
        'itemCode': '<?php echo $order_sku; ?>',
        'productName': '<?php echo $order_product; ?>',
        'category': '<?php echo $order_category; ?>',
        'price': '<?php echo $order_price; ?>',
        'quantity': '<?php echo $order_quantity; ?>'
    }]);

    _ss.push(['_completeTransaction', {
        'transactionID': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>'
    }]);

}]);

</script>


 <!-- End Tracking code -->
 <?php
 }
```

Comment: You will need to do something like `'transactionID': '<?php echo($order->get_transaction_id()) ?>',` in your javascript code. This example is for printing transaction id in javascript code. Similarly you will need to print other values.

Comment: Ah got it. So I just need to find the list of WooCommerce / Wordpress selectors and pop them in place of the examples I guess.

Will try find them and test it out. Thank you zipkindan!

Comment: Glad if it could help you. I would suggest to check the woocommerce order class for getting the required data.

Comment: thanks again @zipkundan

i've gone from clueless beginner to 'almost there' - sort of.

I've updated the code above which I've now deployed. If you've any thoughts on the issues I'm experiencing, also outlined in the update, I'd be most grateful